# Check data replication in zookeeper ensemble

Tags: docker, docker-compose, replication, apache-zookeeper

I'm running a zookeeper ensemble of 3 servers in replicated mode with docker-compose. 
My question would be how exactely can i check that the data replication is working correctly?

Many thanks in advance!

p.s. in the normal bash (alpine) or zk cli would be best

Comment: You must show more details about your configuration.

Comment: This is my docker-compose.yml file: 

[link] (http://imgur.com/a/rgV7D)
i then connected to one of the servers with zk cli and added a znode

now i wanna check if replication of data worked